# Disable allocationSize Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I would know like how to disable allocationSize=50 in my application.
I would like that hibernate generate allocationSize=1 for all entities.

There is a file or configuration that I can apply for all entities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a global generator in an **orm.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">

  <sequence-generator name="global_seq_gen" allocation-size="1" initial-value="1" />

</entity-mappings>
```

And then simply reference this generator in your Entity mappings:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "global_seq_gen")
private Long id;
```

Comment: My Hi, I don't know how to configure the file orm.xml in my app.
My configuration is like for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811261/orm-xml-files-without-persistense-xml

I also use:
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

Comment: Just add it next to your persistence.xml in your META-INF folder.

Comment: I don't have persistence.xml.
I have persistence-context.xml of spring framework.
I try this configuration:
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/user.orm.xml</value>
        </list>
   </property>    

I put the file "orm.xml" in META-INF folder.